# Populate array in react-redux-firebase

Tags: react-redux-firebase

`react-redux-firebase` supports replacing ids with the corresponding value in a lookup object – like a join – through a config object called `populates` (and later using a convenient mapping function inside `mapStateToProps`).

Unfortunately, the documentation of `react-redux-firebase` is rather rudimentary in this area (and in others)...

Can someone tell me, whether it's possible to populate a **list** of ids?

For example:

```js
// from:
{ friends: [1, 27, 42] }

// to:
{ friends: [
  { id: 1, name: 'Charlie' },
  { id: 27, name: 'Parker' },
  { id: 42, name: 'Brown' },
] }
```

Comment: Been a while, but did you ever find an aswer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Testing version `3.0.0`, it seems that populating a list works exactly the same as replacing a single field. Instead of receiving back an object you will receive an array of replaced objects.